# Transform a horizontal table row into a vertical one

Tags: codeigniter, uitableview

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.0 and MySQL. I want to display a horizontal data row as a vertical one. When I fetch a single row from the database and echo it, it looks like

```
----------------------------------------
id    | name   | address | email       |
----------------------------------------
1     | Foo    | Bar     | foo@bar.com |
----------------------------------------
```

I have used CodeIgniters table library to generate the above table. instead of this, I want it show like this:

```
------
id : 1
name: foo
address : bar
email: foo@bar.com
-------------------
```

How do I do this with CodeIgniter 2.1.0?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400621/php-arrange-table-content-from-horizontal-to-vertical

Comment: @rooneyl,i saw it, but it didn't help. i am fetching only one row and by $this->table->generate('records'); i m showing the result.
and i want to show it as i mentioned in the question. can you help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any problem to implement my previous answer... Here is the details...
Let me know is it useful or not?
Thanks.

/* for controller */

$data['user_data'] = $this->modle_name->function_name;
modle_name= your modle name where the specific function exists.
    function_name= function into the modle by which you get all the table value from mysql db.

then write the function currectly in modle and go to the view page:it may be like that

/* model */

```
function function_name(){
$sql = "select * from tablename where condition";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
}
```

/* for view */

```
<?php foreach ($user_data as $data) {?>
<tr>
 <?php echo 'ID:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['id']); ?>
 <?php echo 'Name:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['name']); ?>
 <?php echo 'Address:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['address']); ?>
 <?php echo 'E-mail:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['email']); ?>
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem has a very easy solution by using a single `foreach` loop in your view page:

```
/* for controller */    
    $data['user_data'] = $this->modle_name->function_name;
    modle_name= your modle name where the specific function exists.
    function_name= function into the modle by which you get all the table value from mysql db.
```

then write the function currectly in modle and go to the view page:

```
/* for view */

<?php foreach ($user_data as $data) {?>
<tr>
 <?php echo 'ID:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['id']); ?>
 <?php echo 'Name:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['name']); ?>
 <?php echo 'Address:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['address']); ?>
 <?php echo 'E-mail:' . '  ' ?>
 <?php echo ($data['email']); ?>
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have figured out one solution to this problem, but i think it is not the best way.
instead of using table library, i have changed my model,controller and view like this:
model:

```
function detail()
{
 $this->db->where('id',$this -> session -> userdata('id'));
 $query=$this->db->get('user');
 $row=$query->row_array();
 return $row;
}
```

controller:

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
$this->my_model->detail();
$data=array(
 'id'=>$query['id'],
 'name'=>$query['name'],
 'address'=>$query['address'],
 'email'=>$query['email']
);
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

view:

```
<div>
id : <?php echo $id;?><br/>
name: <?php echo $name;?><br/>
address: <?php echo $address;?><br/>
email: <?php echo $email;?>
</div>
```

this works perfectly. but i wished to solve this in a more simpler manner.